# What happens to allocated resources after throwing an Exception?

Tags: php, exception

*Exceptions* are worse than `goto` statements, because they are going to each of the higher tires separately, to see if something would eventually catch them up; And they will left the function/method unfinished without freeing up their already allocated resources.

That's the main reason I have seen in many articles that are recommending against the use of *Exceptions*, mostly for C++ and Java developers.

I'm wondering if the same reason goes for PHP as well? The point regarding the PHP is that the script is gonna be finished/terminated usually within seconds from initialization. And I assume -- well, I hope; That PHP core is gonna free up all the resources that have been allocated to that particular script.

That being said, the reason that *Exceptions left resources occupied* wouldn't be a real concern here, because in any case all of those resources will be free soon by the time script finishes.

Is that correct or am I missing something here? If it's correct, then does that mean I can use *Exceptions* in PHP without being worried about *Zombie Resources* or they will stuck there for a while after the script terminates? Is PHP's GC mature enough to take care of those wasted resources?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1mr1qa/when_do_you_throw_exceptions/

Comment: @CodeLover Thanks for the link, but I seem not to see if it's really addressing my question or not? Would you mind to point at where should I exactly look for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will free allocated memory, close resources and such when the associated variables go out of scope. That's PHP's primary mechanism for deallocation: scope. Since the scope of a function is typically very quickly exited when an exception is thrown, everything in it will be deallocated the same way as if you'd return from the function regularly. The same will also happen once the scripts ends, as you said.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I didn't know that the de-allocation is on a _Scope_ basis. That's seems quite clever to me.